# custom function for scatterplot in bokeh not running

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, scatter-plot, scatter

dataset i am working on:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/gauravsahani/housing-in-london-for-beginners/data

i am using bokeh and have produced the following scatter plot

```
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(df,av=df.average_price,cr=df.no_of_crimes,ar=df.area))

p=figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width',toolbar_location=None,height=500,
        x_axis_label='Average Salary',y_axis_label='crime rate')
p.xaxis.formatter = BasicTickFormatter(use_scientific=False)

p.add_layout(Legend(), 'right')

p.scatter(x='av',y='cr',source=source,size=9,alpha=0.4,legend_field='area',fill_color=factor_cmap('area',palette=magma(34),factors=df.area.unique()))
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None

p.legend.label_text_font_size='12px'
p.legend.padding=4
p.legend.orientation='vertical'
p.legend.spacing=-7

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Area','@ar')]))

show(p)
```

I am trying to produce a custom function for reusability which is the following:

```
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(df,av=df.average_price,
                                  cr=df.no_of_crimes,
                                  ar=df.area))
tooltips=[('Area','@ar')]
          
def scatter(source,x,y,xlabel=None,ylabel=None,size=None,alpha=None,legend_field=None,fill_color=None):
    p=figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width',
                   toolbar_location=None,
                   height=500,
                   x_axis_label=xlabel,
                   y_axis_label=ylabel)
          
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
    p.xaxis.formatter = BasicTickFormatter(use_scientific=False)
    p.legend.label_text_font_size='12px'
    p.legend.padding=4
    p.legend.orientation='vertical'
    p.legend.spacing=-7
          
    p.scatter(source=source,x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,legend_field=legend_field,fill_color=fill_color)
          
    return p
          
p=scatter(source,x='av',y='cr')
          
show(p)
```

however I keep getting an error and I cant seem to figure out why since both my x and y columns are numerical values and already run successfuly when not working with a function. the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [234], in <cell line: 24>()
     20     p.scatter(source=source,x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,legend_field=legend_field,fill_color=fill_color)
     22     return p
---> 24 p=scatter(source,x='av',y='cr')
     26 show(p)

Input In [234], in scatter(source, x, y, xlabel, ylabel, size, alpha, legend_field, fill_color)
     17 p.legend.orientation='vertical'
     18 p.legend.spacing=-7
---> 20 p.scatter(source=source,x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,legend_field=legend_field,fill_color=fill_color)
     22 return p

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\glyph_api.py:962, in GlyphAPI.scatter(self, *args, **kwargs)
    960     return self.circle(*args, **kwargs)
    961 else:
--> 962     return self._scatter(*args, marker=marker_type, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\_decorators.py:86, in glyph_method.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
     84 if self.coordinates is not None:
     85     kwargs.setdefault("coordinates", self.coordinates)
---> 86 return create_renderer(glyphclass, self.plot, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\_renderer.py:116, in create_renderer(glyphclass, plot, **kwargs)
    113 # handle the mute glyph, we always set one
    114 muted_visuals = pop_visuals(glyphclass, kwargs, prefix='muted_', defaults=glyph_visuals, override_defaults={'alpha':0.2})
--> 116 glyph = make_glyph(glyphclass, kwargs, glyph_visuals)
    117 nonselection_glyph = make_glyph(glyphclass, kwargs, nonselection_visuals)
    118 selection_glyph = make_glyph(glyphclass, kwargs, selection_visuals)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting\_renderer.py:145, in make_glyph(glyphclass, kws, extra)
    143 kws = kws.copy()
    144 kws.update(extra)
--> 145 return glyphclass(**kws)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model\model.py:128, in Model.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    121 def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    122 
    123     # "id" is popped from **kw in __new__, so in an ideal world I don't
    124     # think it should be here too. But Python has subtle behavior here, so
    125     # it is necessary
    126     kwargs.pop("id", None)
--> 128     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    129     default_theme.apply_to_model(self)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py:206, in HasProps.__init__(self, **properties)
    203 self._unstable_themed_values = {}
    205 for name, value in properties.items():
--> 206     setattr(self, name, value)
    208 self._initialized = True

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py:230, in HasProps.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    228 properties = self.properties(_with_props=True)
    229 if name in properties:
--> 230     return super().__setattr__(name, value)
    232 descriptor = getattr(self.__class__, name, None)
    233 if isinstance(descriptor, property): # Python property

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py:283, in PropertyDescriptor.__set__(self, obj, value, setter)
    280     class_name = obj.__class__.__name__
    281     raise RuntimeError(f"{class_name}.{self.name} is a readonly property")
--> 283 value = self.property.prepare_value(obj, self.name, value)
    284 old = self._get(obj)
    285 self._set(obj, old, value, setter=setter)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\dataspec.py:515, in SizeSpec.prepare_value(self, cls, name, value)
    513 except TypeError:
    514     pass
--> 515 return super().prepare_value(cls, name, value)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\bases.py:365, in Property.prepare_value(self, owner, name, value, hint)
    363 else:
    364     obj_repr = owner if isinstance(owner, HasProps) else owner.__name__
--> 365     raise ValueError(f"failed to validate {obj_repr}.{name}: {error}")
    367 if isinstance(owner, HasProps):
    368     obj = owner

ValueError: failed to validate Scatter(id='40569', ...).size: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Float)) or Float, got None
```

any help would be great

Comment: You are passing None for the scatter size, which is not a valid value.

Comment: thank you @bigreddot I realised this was the issue aswel as ensuring 'alpha' also had a numerical value. the main issue is "legend_field" which doesnt allow None as a value in the function even though a string needs to be passed through. any workarounds?

Comment: 'value error: legend_field value must be value string'

Comment: You are also passing None for the `legend_field` based on the code above, which is more or less what the error message states. Any time you have a `ValueError`, a good first step is to print the value in question. That will often point out what the problem is.

Comment: i have tried legend_field=str(None) in the function argument but its still not running. any other suggestions?

Comment: `legend_field` need to be the name of one of the columns in the `ColumnDataSource`, to generate a grouped legend based on the data values in that column? Is that what you actually want to happen, as opposed to a simple label? The docs are very thorough describing options for legends: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#legends

Comment: Oh I see thank you for the documentation. I will try this at work first thing tomorrow. When manually creatinf scatter plots I've never had to reference the legend in the CDS as I've always included "df" in the CDS. my plan was to include a legend field in the custom function however if this isn't possible I'll resort to the CDS method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def scatter(source,x,y,xlabel=None,ylabel=None,size=5,alpha=1,legend_field=str(None),fill_color=None):

    p=figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width',
    toolbar_location=None,
    height=500,
    x_axis_label=xlabel,
    y_axis_label=ylabel)  

    p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
    p.xaxis.formatter = BasicTickFormatter(use_scientific=False)
    p.legend.label_text_font_size='12px'
    p.legend.padding=4
    p.legend.orientation='vertical'
    p.legend.spacing=-7

    if legend_field == str(None):
        p.scatter(source=source,x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,fill_color=fill_color)
    else:
        p.scatter(source=source,x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,legend_field=legend_field,fill_color=fill_color)

    return p
```